# Criando dois links com caminho de um Explode

Tags: php, html, sql

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto e junto ao formulário, o usuário pode fazer o upload de um arquivo. No caso, a parte de cadastro junto ao upload(s) eu já consegui fazer, agora estou criando a exibição/alteração do registro. E nisso que estou empacando.

No caso, eu registrei o caminho do upload e joguei no banco trazendo esse caminho para a tela de exibição/alteração com explode para dividir os arquivos...porém mesmo com explode, ele ainda entende como um link só. Conforme segue abaixo.

```
<? 

#definir o char-set da página 
setlocale(LC_ALL,"pt_BR"); 
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=windows-1252');    

set_time_limit(120); //Tempo limite de execução 
ERROR_REPORTING (E_ERROR); //Exibe somente erros fatais 

 #Variáveis de Data e Hora  
$dataAt = date('d/m/Y');    
$horaAt = date('H:i:s');

$inserir = 0;   

$usuario = strtolower($_SERVER["LOGON_USER"]);
$usuario_1 = split('\\\\', $usuario);
$usuario = $usuario_1[1];



//variaveis para execução do SQL 
SQL(); 
global $sql; 

$idd = $_REQUEST["id"];//Varíavel para buscar o campo id do registro 

//echo "O ID para alteração é o: ".$idd; 
//echo "<BR><BR>"; 

#Cria a consulta inicial 
$altEve = "SELECT [id],[mudanca],[tarefa]
  ,[descricao],[ambiente],[empresa],[reg_afet]
  ,[sist_afet],[hw_afet],[host_name],[serv_afet]
  ,[conclusao],[obs],[data_exec],[obs2],[upload]
    FROM [Passagem].[dbo].[tb_eventos_relev_tst] WHERE ID= $idd"; 

//echo $altPas;
//echo "<BR>";

#realiza a busca pelos dados do registro 
$result = $sql->execute($altEve); 
    if($tbl = $result) 
        { 
            $codigo = $tbl["id"];
            $codigo = $tbl["mudanca"];
            $codigo = $tbl["tarefa"];
            $codigo = $tbl["descricao"];
            $codigo = $tbl["ambiente"];
            $codigo = $tbl["empresa"];
            $codigo = $tbl["reg_afet"];
            $codigo = $tbl["sist_afet"];
            $codigo = $tbl["hw_afet"];
            $codigo = $tbl["host_name"];
            $codigo = $tbl["serv_afet"];
            $codigo = $tbl["conclusao"];
            $codigo = $tbl["obs"];
            $codigo = $tbl["obs2"];
            $codigo = $tbl["data_exec"];
            $codigo = $tbl["upload"];
            } 
    else 
        { echo "Registro não localizado"; } 

    #Inicia o tratamento dos registros      
    while (!$result -> EOF) { 
        $id = $result->Fields['id']->Value; 
        $mudanca = $result->Fields['mudanca']->Value;   
        $tarefa = $result->Fields['tarefa']->Value;     
        $descricao = $result->Fields['descricao']->Value;   
        $ambiente = $result->Fields['ambiente']->Value;     
        $empresa = $result->Fields['empresa']->Value;   
        $reg_afet = $result->Fields['reg_afet']->Value;     
        $sist_afet = $result->Fields['sist_afet']->Value;   
        $hw_afet = $result->Fields['hw_afet']->Value;   
        $host_name = $result->Fields['host_name']->Value;   
        $serv_afet = $result->Fields['serv_afet']->Value;   
        $conclusao = $result->Fields['conclusao']->Value;   
        $obs = $result->Fields['obs']->Value;   
        $data_exec = $result->Fields['data_exec']->Value;   
        $obs2 = $result->Fields['obs2']->Value;     
        $upload = $result->Fields['upload']->Value;     


        $dataEx = substr($data_exec, 8,2)."/".substr($data_exec,5,2)."/".substr($data_exec, 0,4);

        //echo $upload;
        //echo "<BR>";
        $uploadExi = explode(' , ',$upload); 
         //foreach($uploadExi as $valores) 
            //{ 
                //echo $valores.'<BR>'; 
            //}


        #Move para o registro seguinte
        $result->MoveNext();

    }
```

E no Html abaixo

```
 ...
 <p>
                <label>Anexo:</label>
                <input type="hidden" name="eveArquivoAntigo" id="idArquivoAntigo" value="<? echo $upload; ?>" /> 
                <? 
                    if($upload == '' || $upload == 'Sem arquivo anexo') { 
                        echo 'Não existem arquivos anexos para este registro'; 
                    } else { 
                 ?> 
                    <a href="../UTILS/<?foreach($uploadExi as $valores) { echo $valores; } ?>" target="_blank">
                    <?foreach($uploadExi as $valores)   { echo $valores.'<BR>'; }?></a><br> 
                <?  
                    } 
                ?>
            </p>
            <p> 
                <label for="idArquivo">Alterar anexo:</label>
                <input type="file" name="eveArquivo[]" id="idArquivo" disabled />
            </p><br>
```

No caso o que poderia ser feito para que cada parte do arquivo seja tratada com um link diferente? 
E aproveitando ao alterar(campo abaixo) o arquivo antigo provavelmente terá que ser excluido do servidor...existe algum outro modo além do Ulink?

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que o erro esteja no `foreach` não estas a faze-lo correctamente com o *hyperlink*?

```
<?php
if($upload == '' || $upload == 'Sem arquivo anexo') { 
    echo 'Não existem arquivos anexos para este registro'; 
} else { 
    foreach($uploadExi as $valores)   { 
        echo '<a href="../UTILS/' . $valores . '" target="_blank">'.$valores.'</a><BR>';
    }
} 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Essa parte deu certo. Agora falta a segunda pergunta relativo a exclusão do Link. Estou fazendo deste modo no caso

```
if($upload == '' || $upload == 'Sem arquivo anexo') { 
                        echo 'Não existem arquivos anexos para este registro'; 
                    } else { 
                        foreach($uploadExi as $valores)   { 
                            echo '<a href="../UTILS/' . $valores . '" target="_blank" >'.$valores.'</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <input type="text" name="hidValor" value="'.$valores.'"/>
                            <input type="submit" name="ExcluirAnexo" value="Excluir Anexo" class="botaoExc"><BR>
                            '; //disabled
                    } }
```

O arquivo Regista2.php é este

```
//Inicia o Case/Switich de opções 
switch(get_post_action('Incluir','Alterar','Excluir','ExcluirAnexo')) {

    //Incluir registro 
    case 'Incluir':
        //está parte do código está OK 

        break;
    //Alterar registro
    case 'Alterar': 
        //está parte do código está OK

        break;  

        //Exclusão
        case 'Excluir': 
        //está parte do código está OK

        break; 

        //Exclusão de Anexo 
        case 'ExcluirAnexo':    


            $idPag = $_REQUEST['eveId'];//Id da página
            $id = $_REQUEST['hidId']; //Busca campo ID na página 

            echo $id."<BR>";

            $excAnexo = $_REQUEST["hidValor"];
            echo $encAnexo."<BR>";

            //Efetua a consulta no banco 
            $consulta = "SELECT [upload] FROM [dbo].[tb_eventos_relev_tst] REPLACE ('$encAnexo','$encAnexo','') WHERE [id]=$id";
            echo $consulta."<BR>";  
            //Executa a consulta
            //$result = $sql->execute($consulta); 

            //Exibe o resultado 
            echo "O arquivo $encAnexo foi excluído com sucesso<BR>"; 
            echo "<br><p><a href='../FILES/alterar_even_tst.php?id=$idPag'>Clique aqui para voltar a tela de alteração</a></p>";


        break;

        default: 
            //NAda

}
```

No caso a duvida ficaria a mesma em relação a excluir somente uma parte do registro e em relação a usar o  Ulink()...porém neste método nem a varíavel está chegando na outra página...ela chega vazia, somente a de código está aparecendo.

No aguardo desta outra parte.